# OSGi: Register Service with custom property

Tags: service, properties, osgi

I am using Equinox with DS, and I have some services I'd like register with custom properties. I am using:

```
    Hashtable<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<String,Object>();
    properties.put("service.market","ch");
    context.registerService(Workflow.class.getName(), new WorkflowAlternate(), properties);
```

This isn't doing the trick. When I getAllServiceReferences(WorkFlow,null) and interrogate the keys, they all show only objectclass, service.id, service.bundleid, and service.scope.

What do I need to do to register a service (programatically) with custom properties?

As per notes below, I'm editing to add the code I'm using to interrogate the keys. The correct bundles are found and work, but when I ask for keys this way, I get just the four keys above.

```
public void dumpReferences() throws Exception
{
    ServiceReference<?>[] references = context.getAllServiceReferences(Workflow.class.getName(), null);
    for(ServiceReference<?> reference : references)
    {
        String[] keys = reference.getPropertyKeys();
        System.out.println("Bundle: "+reference.getBundle().getSymbolicName());
        for(String key:keys)
        {
            System.out.println("\tKey: "+key+ " ["+reference.getProperty(key)+"]");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what you need to do. Maybe there is something wrong with the interrogating code, can you post that?

Comment: PS if you're using DS (and from our interaction on Twitter I think you are) you can publish a service with properties using the `@Component` annotation and its `property` attribute.

Comment: This is very puzzling. I don't see anything wrong with your code, and I believe it should work. Are you sure that the registration code (first snippet) is actually being executed? Could you try the following... the `registerService` call gives you back a `ServiceRegistration` object. Try calling `getReference` on that and dump the properties in the same way.